# How to set multiple controls on Frame control in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, frame

I am having one Frame control in my Windows 8 metro style app in which i would like to add multiple other controls like textbox, combobox, etc. Basically I would like to create a form which take input from the user and give the result. When i click on button i am using frame to display this things but in a frame it does not allow me to put more than one control.

**It says that content can only be set once.**

If anyone has any idea please help. I am new to Windows 8 so please excuse me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Stack Panel or Grid control to host your nested controls

Hope it helps